# Performing arithmetic operation on certain rows and displaying the result

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, jasper-reports

Below is my table contents:

```
select * from summary_weekly_sales;

DISTRIBUTOR    DATE_OF_ACTIVATION  NUMBER_OF_SALES
-------------- ------------------  ---------------
charan          25-APR-13              23
charan          26-APR-13               2
charan          28-APR-13               5
charan          29-APR-13              50
anil            25-APR-13              13
anil            26-APR-13               4
anil            28-APR-13               5
anil            29-APR-13              30
```

In the ireport DATE_OF_ACTIVATION is the input parameter (but here I am taking date_of_activation as 29-APR-13), I want the output to displayed as below:

```
DISTRIBUTOR    avg_sales_week   NUMBER_OF_SALES
-------------- ---------------  ---------------
charan          10              50

anil            7.33            30
```

where,

**avg_sales_week** is the average week sales per distributor (i.e. 7 days back of 29-APR-13)

i.e. for **charan** distributor average = (5+2+23)/3

**Number_Of_Sales** is the sales done on 29-APR-13

I tried with [wm_concat](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/string-aggregation-techniques.php) function of oracle but its not working as expected.

Is there any way to get the above expected result.

Regards,
Charan

Comment: i thinks that it's not possible to do this request in one shot, because if you have a whre clause like DATE_OF_ACTIVATION = 29-APR-13, you cannot calculate the average sales

Comment: for **anil** as distributor average is (13+4+3)/3 i.e. 10

Comment: Take a look at the Oracle analytic functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would do it:

```
select distributor
,      sum(case when date_of_activation < date '2013-04-29'
           then number_of_sales end)  
       / count(distinct case when date_of_activation < date '2013-04-29' 
           then date_of_activation end) as avg_sales_week   
,      sum(case when date_of_activation=date '2013-04-29' 
           then number_of_sales end) number_of_sales
from   summary_weekly_sales
where  date_of_activation between date '2013-04-29' - 7 and date '2013-04-29'
group by distributor;

DISTRIBUTO AVG_SALES_WEEK NUMBER_OF_SALES
---------- -------------- ---------------
anil           7.33333333              30
charan                 10              50
```

Just replace `date '2013-04-29'` by your parameter name e.g. `p_date` to use in procedure.

Comment: I have never seen a query like this before.

Comment: Hi @Tony, is it possible to get an absolute difference between average_sales_week and number_of_sales in your query

Comment: @kattashri: not sure what you mean - do you mean one minus the other?  if so you could wrap the query in another and `select distributor, avg_sales_week, number_of_sales, number_of_sales-avg_sales_week as difference from ([the query above])`

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
distributor, 
sum(number_of_sales) / 
    (select count(*) from summary_weekly_sales sws2 where sws2.distributor = distributor and sws2.date_of_activation > '29-APR-13' - 7)
as avg_sales_week, 
number_of_sales
FROM summary_weekly_sales
WHERE DATE_OF_ACTIVATION > '29-APR-13' - 7
GROUP BY distributor
```

Maybe this should help.